# object method doesn't like passing in a CGRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

made an object, MyTextBoxCreator. i need to make lots of text boxes dynamically. i want to be able to pass in a frame to the method.

```
.h file
-(UITextField *) standardTextField: (CGRect *) myRec;


.m file
-(UITextField *) standardTextField: (CGRect *) myRect
{
    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 30)];

    UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];
    myTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:textFieldFont size:textFieldFontSize];
    myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
    myTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    myTextField.textColor = [UIColor textFieldTextColor];
    myTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    myTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor textfieldBorderColor]CGColor];
    myTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    myTextField.leftView = paddingView;
    myTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    myTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;

    return myTextField;
}
```

when i try to create the textfield with myRect for the CGRect, i get the error:

```
Sending 'CGRect *' (aka 'struct CGRect *') to parameter of incompatible type 'CGRect" (aka "struct CGRect')
```

i don't understand whats wrong with passing in the CGRect...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't pass a pointer to the `CGRect`, just pass the structure itself.

```
-(UITextField *) standardTextField: (CGRect) myRect;
```

Note that it's a **structure**, not an actual **object**.

Though, if you need to pass in a pointer to the struct, you can dereference it:

```
...
-(UITextField *) standardTextField: (CGRect *) myRect {
CGRect rectStruct = *myRect;
...
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:rectStruct];
...
```

Comment: Maybe a pointer is needed for some obscure reason. In such a case, the OP will need to de-reference it. You should add a line about this in your answer.

Comment: nope, don't need to pass it a pointer, just did it as force of habit. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`initWithFrame:` takes a `CGRect`. You are passing a `CGRect*` parameter.

I think it would be simpler to change your `standardTextField:` signature to take a `CGRect` instead.
Otherwise, you'll need to de-reference the `CGRect` pointer:

```
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:*myRect];
```